# Phalcon PHP Password Bcrypt

Tags: php, phalcon

So, I have setup in my di, the security component, as such...

```
--services.php--
$di->set('security', function(){
    $security = new Phalcon\Security();
    //Set the password hashing factor to 11 rounds
    $security->setWorkFactor(11);
    return $security;
}, true);

--Custom Auth Library (auth.php)--
    $user = Users::findFirstByEmail($login);
    if ($user) {
        if ($this->security->checkHash($password, $user->password)) {
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

but, for some reason, this always returns false...so, to debug, I tried using PHP's password_verify function, the following code is in my view directly:

```
//Returns false
var_dump($this->security->checkHash('password', '$2a$12$aSa7zLEd24zjh2aoUasxd.hbxIm8IQ0/vMf/8p4LTYI3VtZMJ62Pe'));
//Returns True
var_dump(password_verify('password', '$2a$12$aSa7zLEd24zjh2aoUasxd.hbxIm8IQ0/vMf/8p4LTYI3VtZMJ62Pe'));
```

What am I missing???

Comment: If I didn't provide enough information, please let me know.

Comment: FYI: You don't need to `echo var_dump`.  `var_dump` doesn't return anything, it prints to the screen.

Comment: I realize that, but I already typed var_dump to debug this in the controller, and model, and already had an echo line...it is counter-productive, but for debugging, it does no harm. At least, I don't think it does, but good point.

Comment: It does no harm, just felt like pointing it out :)

Comment: eh, corrected anyways

Comment: How are you hashing the passwords to begin with?  With `password_hash` or `$this->security->hash`?

Comment: `$this->security->hash("password");` then I stored that value in the db manually, and attempted to verify using `$this->security->checkHash();`

Comment: but that shouldn't matter, according to: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/1912

Comment: Try to set it to 12 rounds instead of 11.

Comment: did that already too, in fact, that is what it was set at initially, and I adjusted to 11 afterwards to see if maybe that had something to do with it.

Comment: I thought the "12" in `$2a$12$` was the cost, but I could be wrong.  If that didn't help, then I'm not sure, sorry.

Comment: just switched it back to 12 with the same problem.

Comment: @JustinE just as sanity check, you could try running [this script](http://pastebin.com/6tNRgyXg). If you get two true values from that, your problem might be caused by something else in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so it seems that if I set both the hash, and the password to a variable, it parses both statements correctly.

I appreciate all of the help, but this was the final solution.

```
$password = $pass;
$hash = '$2a$12$lDL2eQ1GLJsJhKgPvU6agOnHpwNSBYPtWHF/O/aTvyISzI.ugjyLC';

var_dump($this->security->checkHash($password, $hash));
var_dump(password_verify($password, $hash));
```

Comment: What is the point of using this line $password = $pass; ? Thank you

Comment: That was part of a more complex hashing algorithm that was applied to the password after php hashed it. To simplify the question, I omitted these details. It doesn't hurt, and requires almost no processing power.

Comment: I'm using Bcrypt for my api as well, but after I setup the di, and use $password_hash = $this->security->hash($password);
    echo json_encode($password_hash); It doesn't echo anything, just blank. But when I use sha1, it echo the right hash. Did I do anything wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to [Security::checkHash returns true when using with a non-bcrypt hash](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/1912), which has been fixed a few days ago.

Looking at the code, the problem might be within this block, can you verify that the user model gets loaded, so does his hashed password?

```
$user = Users::findFirstByEmail($login);
if ($user) {
    if ($this->security->checkHash($password, $user->password)) {
       return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: It does, because I can remove `if ($this->security->checkHash($password, $user->password)) {
       return true;
    }` and add return `$user->password`, and it echos the hashed password.

Comment: Not exactly related to my issue, as I am positive, and have verified it is getting the correct hash from the database.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone gets here and none of the answers above seem to help, and you keep feeling more and more dumb, **check the password column length in your users table!!**. In my case it was a varchar(50) and the hash gives you 60 chars.

Doing this (pointed above) http://pastebin.com/6tNRgyXg, helped me realise that something other than the code was wrong.

Comment: My password length was set to max length of a varchar which was 255 characters so that was not the issue. Still a good thing to check...+1